# dim.xml and cub.xml are corrupted

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2014, olap, xmla

After restart my server outputs the following error massages:

```
     Errors in the metadata manager.
     An error occurred when loading the Unicube cube, from the file, '\\?\E:\DB\Unicube.0.db\ClientBase.3966.cub.xml'.
     Errors in the metadata manager.
     An error occurred when loading the Shop dimension, from the file, '\\?\E:\DB\Unicube.0.db\Shop.247.dim.xml'.
     File system error: The following file is corrupted: Physical file: \\?\E:\DB\Unicube.0.db\Shop.239.dim\247.ID 1.kstore. Logical file .
```

I tried to restart Analysis Server and open it from Visual Studio, but the project can't open due the same massage.

How can I recover cube properly? XMLs are pretty similar to XMLA syntax, however It's too much manual work I expect to make it reusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated my cube db from all xmls by removing some load-specific code and renaming **load** tag to **create** and running them as xmla code. There are bunch of xml files, so you'll need some automation.